# league of legends client connection issues

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues

Ever since I started to play league (about a month ago, so not too long) I've been having a nasty problem with the client (the website doesn't like me either) never wanting to stay connected. But the thing is, its only the client, the game it self seems to work fine, with the only connection issues coming from my not-so-great internet

[image: Trying to reconnect]

this guy keeps popping up, making the client almost unusable. As whenever it pops up it throws me back to the home screen, and sometimes removes me from the queue.

I just reset my firewall, then I ran the 'Hextech Repair Tool' so I'm hoping its not my firewall

btw, my ISP is Xplornet

and I have a wired connection to our router

I'm using the default port on my motherboard, no special lan card or anything like that

and I'm only using the windows firewall and windows defender

Note about the website: it either doesn't load (saying the connection was reset) or it sometimes only 'half-loads' where only some of the stuff is there, and about none of the buttons work, and on the rare case it properly loads; but it only happens with the league websites, nothing else.

Edit: I'd love to use the Legacy Client, but yeah, not an option here

Edit2: got the legacy client, same problem

[image]

Comment: You are using the Beta version of the new client. It has several issues that haven't been fixed yet. One option would be to use the Legacy Client, and see if it works there (thus it's a problem with the client) or if it's an unrelated issue

Comment: think I got the Legacy Client to work, had to use Compatibility Mode for win XP

Comment: maybe try contacting LoL support. they may be able to help more

Comment: Do you have Service Pack 3? From the [**system requirements**](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201752654-Minimum-and-Recommended-System-Requirements#section-windows) page, Windows XP (Service Pack 3 ONLY) is supported. "*We no longer support Windows XP Service Pack 1 or 2. Since Windows XP 64-bit doesn't have a Service Pack 3, you will need to upgrade to a more recent version of Windows to play League of Legends.*"

Comment: @mbomb007 I got the legacy client to work, but it has the same problem as the beta client

Comment: That's not what I asked. I asked if you have SP 3.